# Python 3.7 with regular expressions: Why can I no longer substitute with a string containing a backslash (\)?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, python-3.7

For my problem, I've got a very simple example:

```
import re
my_string = re.sub(r"Hello", r"\Greetings", "Hello Folks!")
print(my_string)
```

The above, in Python 3.6, will print `\Greetings Folks!` to the standard output. Let's try this again in Python 3.7.0 or 3.7.4 (the versions which I was able to test). What happens? We receive an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/re.py", line 192, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/re.py", line 309, in _subx
    template = _compile_repl(template, pattern)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/re.py", line 300, in _compile_repl
    return sre_parse.parse_template(repl, pattern)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/sre_parse.py", line 1024, in parse_template
    raise s.error('bad escape %s' % this, len(this))
re.error: bad escape \G at position 0
```

Why is this? Is there a change in Python 3.7 which I've missed? What's the proper way around this problem?

Comment: Just a hunch, try doubling up the \.

Comment: This is due to a change in Python 3.7: "Changed in version 3.7: Unknown escapes in repl consisting of '\' and an ASCII letter now are errors." https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there was a change. From the docs about [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub):

> *Changed in version 3.7*: Unknown escapes in *repl* consisting of `'\'` and an ASCII letter now are errors.

So just double up the backslash:

```
my_string = re.sub(r"Hello", r"\\Greetings", "Hello Folks!")
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're using the `\G` construct, which you could probably use if you would have installed `regex` module. Either remove that or add another backslash might be options.

```
import re
my_string = re.sub(r"Hello", r"\\Greetings", "Hello Folks!")
print(my_string)
```

---

Alternative:

```
$pip install regex
```

or

```
$pip3 install regex
```

Then,

```
import regex
my_string = regex.sub(r"Hello", r"\Greetings", "Hello Folks!")
print(my_string)
```

#### Output

```
\Greetings Folks!
```

Comment: The [`regex` info](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) says `\G` is a "search anchor" so I don't think it makes any sense in the replacement argument. But you're right about doubling up the backslash.